# Promise.all – resolve callback fires although a Promise is rejected

Tags: javascript, promise

While playing around with Promises to understand how they work, I noticed something I can't explain.

Given this example:

```
var A = function () {
    return Promise.resolve();
};

var B = function () {
    return Promise.reject();
};

var c = A();
var d = B();

c.then(
  function () { console.log('A success'); },
  function () { console.log('A fail'); }
);

d.then(
  function () { console.log('B success'); },
  function () { console.log('B fail'); }
);

Promise.all([c, d]).then(
  function () { console.log('all success'); },
  function () { console.log('all fail'); }
);
```

First the single resolve/reject callbacks fire, followed by the reject callback of `Promise.all`. This is expected because `B` rejects the Promise.

But when written like the, the resolve callback of `Promise.all` fires:

```
var A = function () {
    return Promise.resolve();
};

var B = function () {
    return Promise.reject();
};

var c = A().then(
  function () { console.log('A success'); },
  function () { console.log('A fail'); }
);
var d = B().then(
  function () { console.log('B success'); },
  function () { console.log('B fail'); }
);

Promise.all([c, d]).then(
  function () { console.log('all success'); },
  function () { console.log('all fail'); }
);
```

This is unexpected since one of the two Promises is rejected, so the Promise returned by `all` should be rejected too.

What is happening here – does is have something to do with return values? Do I need to return a new Promise somewhere?

Comment: Totally expected behavior, because your handling the exeption..  Don't handle your expections, and then your all will catch them. Or alternatively return a rejection in your rejection handlers.

Comment: You are not waiting for `B`, you are waiting for the promise returned by `B`'s `then`.

Comment: In the first one you've already caught the error in the first `then` call, and the promise chain resets itself after that, as the error has been handled.

Comment: See also [When is .then(success, fail) considered an antipattern for promises?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662289/when-is-thensuccess-fail-considered-an-antipattern-for-promises)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two examples look similar, but are not identical. Here is the [documentation](https://www.promisejs.org/api/) for `then` (emphasis mine):

> Calls `onFulfilled` or `onRejected` with the fulfillment value or rejection reason of the promise (as appropriate) and returns a new promise **resolving to** the return value of the called handler.

In your first example, `d` is set to the result of `B()`, which is a rejected promise. A new promise means that something is logged, but `d` is not changed.

In your second example, `d` is changed to the result of `B().then(...)`, which is a resolved promise.

You probably want to `throw` in your rejection handler.

Answer (score 0):

You are suppressing error in the second case:

```
// d is promise which suppressed error from B()
var d = B().then(
  function () { console.log('B success'); },
  function () { console.log('B fail'); }
);
```

You should re-throw error if you want `d` to be rejected as well:

```
var d = B().then(
  function () { console.log('B success'); },
  function (e) { console.log('B fail'); throw e; }
);
```